# DT::datatable display

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

in the following code, the column names disappear when the line "container=..." is uncommented.

```
require(DT)

DT::datatable(cars[1:5,]
    #, container=htmltools::tags$table(class="display")
)
```

Looking at the *Page Source* in the browser, the difference is the following.  Container commented:

```
"container": "<table>\n  <thead>\n    <tr>\n      <th>speed</th>\n      <th>dist</th>\n    </tr>\n  </thead>\n</table>",
```

Container not commented:

```
"container": "<table class=\"display\"></table>",
```

Any idea how they can both be made to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the column names get removed if you change the `container` option.
If you look at the code of the function, available [here](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/blob/master/R/datatables.R), you can see line 75 what happens when you don't set a `container`:

```
  if (missing(container)) container = tags$table(
    id = id,
    tags$thead(tags$tr(lapply(escapeColNames(colnames, escape), tags$th)))
  )
```

When the `container` option is missing, a default container containing the headers is generated. The `escapeColNames` function is defined later on, it is just used to clean up the header names.

When the `container` option is set, this code is not run and the container is just what you give in the option, so you have to add the column names yourself.

You could for example do (without any escaping):

```
 DT::datatable(cars[1:5,],
    container=htmltools::tags$table(class="display",
          tags$thead(tags$tr(lapply(as.list(colnames(cars)), tags$th))))
)
```

Comment: can you pls help with conditional formatting [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28754064/dt-conditional-formatting-for-column).  thx.