# DT conditional formatting for column

Tags: r, datatables

I need some help with conditional formatting for DT::datatable. I would like to highlight a couple of names in the following example by printing them in italics.  The names which need to be highlighted are in a vector `name.highlight <- c("ABC","JKL")`

```
require(DT)

mydf <- data.frame(name=c("ABC","DEF","GHI","JKL","MNO","PQR"), value=1:6)
DT::datatable(mydf)
```

Based on what I see [here](http://rstudio.github.io/DT/) and [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render), seems like I need to use render.  I have no idea how to write the JS code or how I can pass in a vector/container with all the strings which need to be highlighted.

```
datatable(mydf, options = list(columnDefs = list(list(
targets = 0, render = JS("function(data, type, full, meta) {", ..., "}")
))))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
datatable(mydf, options = list(columnDefs = list(list(
    targets = 0, render = JS(
        "function(data, type, full, meta) {",
            "italic_words=['ABC','JKL']",
            "return type === 'display' && italic_words.indexOf(data) != -1 ?",
            "'<i>'+data+'</i>' : data;",
        "}")
))))
```

I defined the italic_words variable in the javascript function. The variable contains an array of all the words you want in italic. Then I used the indexOf() javascript function. If the name isn't in the variable italic_words, this function will return -1, and the name will not be italicized.

Comment: if you want to define the italic words with the vector you could do: `render = JS(paste0("function(data, type, full, meta) { italic_words=['",paste(name.highlight,collapse="','"),
                                       "']; return type === 'display' && italic_words.indexOf(data) != -1 ? '<i>'+data+'</i>' : data;}"))`

Comment: Thank you both.  That's exactly how I just re-wrote it.    `highlight.str <- paste0("'",paste(name.highlight, collapse="','"),"'")`  and `itaJS <- sprintf("function(data, type, full, meta) {
            italic_words=[%s]
            return type === 'display' && italic_words.indexOf(data) != -1 ?
            '<i>'+data+'</i>' : data;
        }", highlight.str)`  and finally `render = JS(itaJS)`.  I do appreciate your getting back so quickly.

Comment: Note: to get this example working, I had to use `targets = 1` rather than `targets = 0`.